# Is there a way to map a repeating import path in Webpack/NextJs?

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

I have a NextJs Project (v14.1.3) and I was wondering if there's a way to make it so that this import

```js
import foo from 'path/to/foo/foo'
```

Could instead be written as

```js
import foo from 'path/to/foo'
```

While still keeping the `foo` file inside the `foo` directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an import map https://github.com/WICG/import-maps, e.g.,

```
  <script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "Buffer": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/08b19ba88c98a465dd09bcd8a04606f6/raw/f7ae1e77fb146843455628042c8fa47aec2644eb/buffer-bun-bundle.js",
        "base32-encode": "https://esm.sh/base32-encode@2.0.0",
        "cborg": "https://esm.sh/cborg@1.10.2",
        "commander": "https://esm.sh/commander@4.1.1",
        "mime": "https://esm.sh/mime@2.6.0",
        "to-data-view": "https://esm.sh/to-data-view@2.0.0",
        "wbn": "https://esm.sh/wbn@0.0.9",
        "wbn-sign-webcrypto": "./wbn-sign.js",
        "zod": "https://esm.sh/zod@3.22.4"
      }
    }
  </script>
```

```
const { Buffer } = await import("Buffer");
```

and

```
import { BundleBuilder as BundleBuilder2 } from "wbn";
import mime from "mime";
import { combineHeadersForUrl } from "wbn";
import { IntegrityBlockSigner, WebBundleId } from "wbn-sign-webcrypto";
```

Node.js doesn't support import maps so you'll have to use their loader mechanism, something like https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/api/module.md#import-from-https.